# array.push does not work in FF, but works in Chrome... any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This only works in Chrome, not FF:

```
    var menu = new Array();
    $.couch.db("foo").allDocs({
            success: function(d) {
                    for(var i=0;i<=d.total_rows-1;i++){
                            menu.push(d.rows[i].id);
                    };
            }
    });
    console.log(menu);
```

I can console.log "menu" inside the function, but not outside. It's like it looses its scope. Any ideas?

Comment: Your code looks good and should work as you expect.

Comment: Is the `success` callback executing after to the `console.log` at the bottom? This could just be a timing issue as the result of a race condition.

Comment: javascript (with the exception of html5 web workers) isn't multithreaded, so there's no real race conditions

Answer (score 3):

Your `success` function gets called later, once you've received a response from $.couch.db, so when you reach `console.log(menu);` you still get the initial value.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the response. I suppose I should have thought about this. I suppose it's a bit bad practice regardless to set a variable inside an ajax call, that it going to be called later. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `var menu = [];` instead of `new Array()` - it shouldn't make any difference, but you never know.

Also, try putting `console.log(menu);` inside the loop, and see... oh, wait.

Forget the above, I just re-read the code.

I'm pretty sure `allDocs()` is an asynchronous function. You're trying to access the result after you started the function, but before it completed. All code that relies on `menu` MUST be in the `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your function works asynchronous so, that when you console.log(menu) outside of the function it shows original state of the menu.

For example, in jQuery when you're using ajax function you can set parameter "**async**" to **false** so that response would be assigned to variable correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are pushing data to the menu array inside a callback. What this means is that your code executes somehow like this:

1. new array is created
2. $.couch.db() is called which does something (some asynchronous task, which causes the execution flow to continue)
3. console.log() is called which usually prints a empty array since menu is empty
4. $.couch.db() finished doing it's business and has called your "success" callback which fills your array

But, there can be cases where your callback is executed before reaching the console.log() ... so really you are dealing with a race condition here.